# Addition of different sized numbers in assembley

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, x86-16

I'm asked to write a program to add a byte sized array elements. First 2 bytes are the number of elements in the array.

The array may contain thousands of numbers so I should put the sum in 32-bit register (e.g. `ax:dx`) but the problem is that I don't know how to take a byte from memory then add it to a 32-bit register (or a double variable in memory).

I have tried adding using a 16-bit register and a word variable in memory. Here is the code:

```
array db 07, 00, 30, 10, 77, 14, 9, 54, 100
sum dw ?


lea ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

lea bx, array
mov cx, [bx] 
mov bx, 0002h
mov dx, 0000h
Addition:
mov dl, [bx]
mov dh, 00h
add sum, dx
add bx, 1
loop Addition 

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
```

It works correctly. But I want to know how to do that with a 32-bit register and a double variable.

**I use emu8086**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an 8-bit value in `BL` to the 32-bit sum in `DX:AX`:

```
xor bh,bh  ; Clear BH (effectively zero-extends BL into BX)
add ax,bx  ; Add BX to the lower half of the sum
adc dx,0   ; If the lower half wrapped around (the above addition resulted
           ; in a carry), add 1 to the upper half, otherwise add 0.
```

Comment: But how I add DX:AX to a double variable in memory?  For example:    sum DD ?

Comment: The principle is the same. First ADD then ADC: `add [sum],ax` / `adc  [sum+2],dx`